# Python generating column header attributes from unseen csv file into sql table

Tags: python, sql, csv

I understand how to populate an sql table with a csv file by using:

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE  test (name, age, number)')
csvfile = open('test.csv', 'rb')
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
for t in creader:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sentence VALUES (?,?,?)', t)
```

However, I'm faced with an issue where, I dont know what the csv file may hold, thus can't explicitly create a table with named column attributes.  All I know is that the file will have column headers and my question is, how do I set that the headers are the column attributes?  For example:

Row 1 in csv has the (unknown) headers e.g. name, number, group.  I'd like those to be attributes in the table t.

I attempted this:

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (col1, col2);")

with open('data.csv','rb') as fin:
   dr = csv.reader(fin)
   dicts = ({'col1': line[0], 'col2': line[1]} for line in dr)
   to_db = ((i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dicts)

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);", to_db)
con.commit()
```

But the error is that I'm getting a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: On which line is this ValueError occurring?

Comment: cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);", to_db)
  
    to_db = ((i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dicts)
 
    dicts = ({'col1': line[0], 'col2': line[1]} for line in dr)

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an assumption based on your indentation being wrong in the question. You're probably still trying to work with the file after finishing your `with` statement.

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (col1, col2);")

with open('data.csv','rb') as fin:
    dr = csv.reader(fin)
    dicts = ({'col1': line[0], 'col2': line[1]} for line in dr)
    to_db = ((i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dicts)
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);", to_db)
    con.commit()
```

When you're using `with open()` the file is automatically closed when you're finished with it.

The alternative, older method, would be similar to;

```
fin = open('data.csv', 'rb') # opens the csv file
try:
    dr = csv.reader(fin)
    dicts = ({'col1': line[0], 'col2': line[1]} for line in dr)
    to_db = ((i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dicts)
finally:
    f.close()      # closing
```

Comment: oops, yeah the indentation should be in my question